# Hide workspace sidebar

Tags: gnome, workspaces, workspace-switcher

If I set a multiple (dynamic) workspaces option in gnome, the sidebar of an empty workspace doesn't hide until I open a window, a folder, or something. However, the open sidebar hides some desktop folders that are therefore inaccessible directly from the Desktop just like in this picture.

[image]

The sidebar doesn't go away if I click on an empty place on the desktop or any other way. How can I make the sidebar hide even if I just want to stare at my Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You asked about hiding the workspace display. However, that will not solve the issue you really want to solve - the fact that some desktop icons are hidden and inaccessible.

Workspaces in the overview can be hidden with Gnome Shell extensions. The extension [Hide Workspace Thumbnails](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/808/hide-workspace-thumbnails/) by edh can do that.

Still, it will not solve your problem. The reason is that you cannot interact with desktop icons while you are in the application overview. With workspaces displayed or not, you need a click on the representation of the desktop in the overview to first return to your desktop, where you then can interact with desktop icons (if they are not covered by your work, that is).

Comment: I still don't get what would be the option I should check/uncheck in Just perfection (which I already have installed).

Comment: Apparently not. Listed another one.

Comment: That's for the thumbnails, not for the sidebar, as far as I understand?

Comment: I think you better check first yourself.

Comment: I just checked and it definitely doesn't help with the sidebar

Comment: We may not be talking about the same. That extension aims to hide the workspace thumbnails from the Activities overview.